# How to set Timeout limit at ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)

Tags: svcutil.exe

As described at this post

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
```

> Timeout
>
> The tool has a 5 minute timeout when retrieving metadata. This timeout
>   only applies to retrieving metadata over the network. It does not
>   apply to any processing of that metadata.

I am always got timeout error when I try to generate my web service file.

```
HTTP GET Error
    URI: http://localhost/TheProject/Services.svc?wsdl

    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost/TheProject/Services.svc?wsdl'.

    The operation has timed out

If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"
```

So, I usually run the script to generate the file 5 or more times at VS CMD. Then, My files generated successfully.
I am looking way to set the timeout limit, so, I am not run 5 or more times my command.

Please help.